# Why am i encountering an Uncaught ReferenceError in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Iam creating a js function that will switch the content of the body of my page as follows:

```
 var BodySwitcher = {

        initBodySwitcher : function(){
            var self = this;
            $(document).on("click", ".bodySwitcher", function() { 
                var action = $(this).attr("id");
                self.ajaxCall(action, null, $.proxy(self.showBody, this), $.proxy(self.initCall, this));
            });
        },

        ajaxCall : function(action, data, callback, callback1){
            $.ajax({
                url: action,
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                error: function(){
                    alert('Please Contact your Administrator');
                },
                success: function(data){         
                    callback(data);
                },
                complete: function (data){
                    callback1(data);
                }
            });
        },

        showBody : function(data){
            var $container = $("#body_container");
            $container.empty();
            $container.html(data);
        },

        initCall: function(data){
            var $container = $("#body_container");
            var $table = $container.find(".table");
            if ($table.length > 0){ 
                initDataTable($table);
            }
            var $form = $container.find("form");
            if ($form.length > 0){ 
                initForm($form);
            }

        },

        initDataTable : function($table){
            if ($table.length > 0){ 
                $("#"+$table.attr("id")).dataTable( {
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
                } );
            }
        },

        initForm: function($form){
            alert("form");
            var self = this;
            $form.form.validate();
            $formSubmit = $form.find(".button");
            $(document).on("click", $formSubmit, function(){
                var formData = $form.serialize();
                var action = $form.attr("id");
                alert(action);
                self.ajaxCall(action, formData, $.proxy(self.showBody, this), $.proxy(self.initCall, this));
            });
        }

    };
```

But Iam encountering this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: initForm is not defined
```

why? How come it can find the initDataTable  but not the initForm?

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference object properties as normal variables.

```
    initCall: function(data){
        var $container = $("#body_container");
        var $table = $container.find(".table");
        if ($table.length > 0){ 
            BodySwitcher.initDataTable($table);
        }
        var $form = $container.find("form");
        if ($form.length > 0){ 
            BodySwitcher.initForm($form);
        }

    },
```

The reason you didn't get the same error for `initDataTable` is probably because `$table.length` was `0`, so it skipped over that code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `this` instead of `BodySwitcher` in that context?

Comment: I'm not sure, my Javascript OO foo is somewhat meagre. It looks like he just has a single `BodySwitcher` object, he's not defining a class.